# Script from tutorial displaying blank page and getting error in page

Tags: google-maps-api-3

Copied a script below from a tutorial and ran it.
I got a blank screen and a message that said "Done, but with error in page."
Think the line with the error is the one that says
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
there's no error when it's commented out.

What am I doing wrong?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=HERE I PUT THE API KEY WITH NO QUOTES&sensor=false">
      </script>
      <script>
        function initialize()
         {
            var mapProp={
                           center:new google.maps.LatLng(51.508742,-0.120850),zoom:5,mapTypeID:google.maps.MaptypeID.ROADMAP
                        };
            var map=new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("googleMap"),mapProp);
         }
         google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);
      </script>
      <title>
      </title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <div id="googleMap" style="width:500px;height:380px;">
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: it has to be `mapTypeId:google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP` (javascript is case-sensitive)

Comment: What tutorial did you copy the script from?  Does the tutorial work?

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
```

Note case of "MapTypeId".

Comment: Thank you all for writing back.(Dr. Molle and Beetroot-Beetroot)Fixed the MapTypeId and put ()s after initialize in that line but still get same thing. Will try to get better diagnostics. (geocodezip) It was copied from w3schools tutorial on google maps and it works ok there.

Comment: `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);` is correct. Surely `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize());` would throw an error.

Comment: F12 key shows editor in IE 9 that says the error is on the line that says `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);` and the error message is `'google' is undefined`----Beetroot-Beetroot,took out the ()s still same error

Comment: Have tried type="text/javascript" in script tag, putting script at bottom of page, changing compatibililty mode, Firefox with no luck. What else can be causing this problem?

Comment: Should work, however try replacing `google.maps.event.addDomListener(window,'load',initialize);` with `window.onload = initialize;`

Comment: Beetroot-Beetroot, thanks for writing back. That change moved the 'google' undefined error to the assignement of mapProp. Do I need something installed? Could it be I made a mistake registering for the api key?

Comment: I wondered about the API key but I don't think it's the problem. Even if it's wrong, `google` should still be defined.